# Spark dataframe transform in time window

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr

I have two dataframes. [AllAccounts]: contains audit for all accounts for all users

```
UserId, AccountId, Balance, CreatedOn
1, acc1, 200.01, 2016-12-06T17:09:36.123-05:00
1, acc2, 189.00, 2016-12-06T17:09:38.123-05:00  
1, acc1, 700.01, 2016-12-07T17:09:36.123-05:00
1, acc2, 189.00, 2016-12-07T17:09:38.123-05:00
1, acc3, 010.01, 2016-12-07T17:09:39.123-05:00
1, acc1, 900.01, 2016-12-08T17:09:36.123-05:00
```

[ActiveAccounts]: contains audit for only the active account(could be zero or 1) for any user

```
UserId, AccountId, CreatedOn
1, acc2, 189.00, 2016-12-06T17:09:38.123-05:00
1, acc3, 010.01, 2016-12-07T17:09:39.123-05:00
```

I want to transform these into a single DF which is of the format

```
UserId, AccountId, Balance, CreatedOn, IsActive
1, acc1, 200.01, 2016-12-06T17:09:36.123-05:00, false
1, acc2, 189.00, 2016-12-06T17:09:38.123-05:00, true 
1, acc1, 700.01, 2016-12-07T17:09:36.123-05:00, false
1, acc2, 189.00, 2016-12-07T17:09:38.123-05:00, true
1, acc3, 010.01, 2016-12-07T17:09:39.123-05:00, true
1, acc1, 900.01, 2016-12-08T17:09:36.123-05:00, false
```

So based on accounts in ActiveAccounts, i need to flag the rows in first df appropriately. As in the example, acc2 for userId 1 was marked active on 2016-12-06T17:09:38.123-05:00 and acc3 was marked active on 2016-12-07T17:09:39.123-05:00. So btw these time ranges acc2 will be marked true and 2016-12-07T17:09:39 onwards acc3 will be marked true.

What will be a an efficient way to do this.

Comment: You can write an `UDF` to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand properly the account `(1, acc1)` is active between its creation time and that of `(1, acc2)`.

We can do this in a few steps:

- create a data frame with the start/end times for each account
- join with `AllAccounts`
- flag the rows of the resulting dataframe

I haven't tested this, so there may be syntax mistakes.

To accomplish the first task, we need to partition the dataframe by `user` and then look at the next creation time. This calls for a window function:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("UserId").orderBy("StartTime")
val activeTimes = ActiveAccounts.withColumnRenamed("CreatedOn", "StartTime")
  .withColumn("EndTime", lead("StartTime") over window)
```

Note that the last `EndTime` for each user will be `null`. Now join:

```
val withActive = AllAcounts.join(activeTimes, Seq("UserId", "AccountId"))
```

(This should be a left join if you might be missing active times for some accounts.)

Then you have to go through and flag the accounts as active:

```
val withFlags = withActive.withColumn("isActive",
  $"CreatedOn" >= $"StartTime" && 
 ($"EndTime".isNull || ($"CreatedOn" < $"EndTime)))
```